# how can I jsdoc a bind call?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I was trying to annotate a variable with jsdoc so it is read as a function. But using the bind call make the var be annotated as any.

```
var beaFunction = myFunction.bind(null,"some_string");
```

```
//tried those
/**
 * @function 
 * @name getClientConsent
 * @returns {string|null} 
 */
var beaFunction = myFunction.bind(null,"some_string");

/**
 * @function 
 * @returns {string|null} 
 */
var beaFunction = myFunction.bind(null,"some_string");

/**
 * @function 
 */
var beaFunction = myFunction.bind(null,"some_string");
//thing is that having bind here seems to override whatever definition I place
```

```
//myFunction does not need annotation, 
function myFunction(key) {
  var d;
  try {
    d= localStorage.getItem(key);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    d = null;
  }
  return d;
}
```

myFunction returns {string|null} but bind gives any. I tried to annotate it as a function but ts-checker still says it is a any.

Any ideas what I can do here using only es5 features?

Comment: Your question as written perhaps needs clarity - you have it marked as `jsdoc` but there is no annotation in the code you presented here. You might include the actual function and the annotation you attempted.  Kind of feels like you are mixing implementation with declaration (and annotation of that) a bit as it currently stands.  The `bind()` method creates a new function with the `this` set to the provided value but pass `null` as the `this` value.  So your jsdoc annotation should indicate that the "some_string" value first parameter followed by whatever is supplied on subsequent calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the type with Typescript syntax like so:

```js
/**
 * @type {() => string|null}
 */
var beaFunction = myFunction.bind(null, "some_string");
```

Comment: cool, that one worked, and I thought I tried something similar. Thank you